# Android facebook notification image

Tags: android, image

I'm trying to figure out how to create an image with a another image on top of it (overlay?) just like android facebook app notification icon.

For those that have seen/use android facebook app, when there are new notifcation comes in, there will be a red number (1,2,3, etc) appear on top of its blue notification icon.

Any idea how this is done?

Thanks much.

Comment: Have you tried using relative layout?

Comment: Heinrisch can you elaborate more on how relative layout can create this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff's ViewBadger does all the work for you: http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-viewbadger/